# find next friday from a fixed date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I would like to find out the next coming date from a given date.  I am using moment js and below is my code.

```
var startDate = moment("10/1/2014");
var nf = startDate.day("Friday");

alert(startDate);
alert(nf);
```

the code is returning next friday, but the above piece of code is changing the original object (startDate) also to next friday. the returned object is a complex object not sure which property to use.

Updating the question with complete code.

```
var startDate = moment("10/1/2014");
var endDate = moment( '10/31/2014');

var diff = endDate.diff(startDate,'days');

var noOfWeeks = diff / 7;

var nextStartday = startDate;
var nextFriday = moment( startDate).day("Friday");

for (var j = 0; j < noOfWeeks ; j++) {
    newRow.PlStartDateandTime = nextStartday;
    newRow.PlEndDateandTime = nextFriday;

    nextStartday = moment( nextFriday).day("Monday");
    nextFriday = moment( nextStartday).day("Friday");
}
```

My expectation is to find the weekdays in between the given time frame.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
var startDate = moment("10/1/2014");
var nf = moment("10/1/2014").day("Friday");

alert(startDate);
alert(nf);
```

You can also do (as you asked) `var nf = moment(startDate).day("Friday");`

You are setting the day of startDate which is changing it, you need to make a separate object if you want to be able to have two different values.

If your `diff` gives the wrong answer, it's because you set it before changing the dates. It won't dynamically update for you, you need to re assign its value

Comment: can i try some thing like moment(startDate).day("Friday");

Comment: There are two properties _i and  _d. _i is retaining original value and _d is the one which is updating with value of next friday. If i use the same object again to find out next monday the behavior is not as expected. it is going to previous month.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: the object which is returned by moment(startDate).day("Friday") has multiple properties. As explained in my above comment each property is retaining different values.

Comment: What are _i and _d, your code and question never reference them

Comment: In my question, I asked about properties as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63436/discussion-between-brainchild-and-parker).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I count the number of weeks inbetween two days...

```
//Used for counting weeks since
var baseDate = new Date("01/01/2014");

//date is in format 01/01/2014
var startTimeTokens1 = data.filterStartTime.split('/');

//Calculate the startWeek number
var sDate = new Date(startTimeTokens1[0] + "/" + startTimeTokens1[1] + "/" + startTimeTokens1[2]); //sDate looks like 01/07/2014
var stimeDiff = Math.abs(sDate.getTime() - baseDate.getTime());
var sdiffDays = Math.ceil(stimeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

startWeek = (Math.ceil( sdiffDays/7 ) + 1);
```

Comment: so basedate would be week1 and then it would calculate the week number sDate, being 01/07/2014, would also be week1